# No elements after XSL namespace added

Tags: xslt

Any help would be appreciated on this simple (I hope) problem. The `xsl:for-each` fails to find any elements after adding a namespace to this XML doc:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdsort.xsl"?>
    <catalog xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/test" >
      <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      </cd>
      <cd>
        <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
        <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
      </cd>
    </catalog>
```

Here is the XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:vv="http://www.mycompany.com/test"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="vv:catalog/cd">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, it is a simple question; it's asked by someone on this list nearly every day. Google for XSLT default namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the default namespace for the whole document so the child elements in the xpaths also need a prefix:

```
<xsl:for-each select="vv:catalog/vv:cd">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="vv:title" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="vv:artist" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks.  ok I made the change but I am still getting no output after the table headings

Comment: It works for me, I've put my working version of the `for-each` loop into the answer.